# Is there a special name for a condition which will break a loop if it increments a set number of times

Tags: javascript, terminology, loops

Is there a name for including a limitation in a loop structure to prevent it from running if its primary condition becomes unwieldy.

For example

```
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++){

   some_function();

}
```

but if len is somewhere set to ten million, I don't want to run it, so I would do something like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < len && i < 50; i++){

   some_function();

}
```

Is there a name for this type of hard-coded condition?

Comment: It might be a form of a guard: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_(computer_science)

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner This sounds pretty much exactly right. Why did you submit as a comment and not an answer?

Comment: Ok, I'll write it up as an answer.

Comment: Aren't guards usually in a separate `if` statement, or at least separated by an `else` clause?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I think this could be considered a more compact guard that can't have an `else`.

Comment: @Frustrated I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be a type of a *guard*. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_(computer_science)

> In computer programming, a guard is a boolean expression that must evaluate to true if the program execution is to continue in the branch in question.

In your case, `i < 50` is the guard on the loop, preventing it from executing if `i` is too large.

I think a guard would usually be written as:

```
if (len< MAX_VALUE)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        do_stuff();
    }
}
//optional else-clause to warn when guard-condition is violated.
//else 
//   ERROR("Value for i is too big!!");
```

This form would allow you to write an `else` clause (where you could warn the user about invalid value of `i`, perhaps). Your compact form, where you include it in the loop condition doesn't allow for an `else`, but maybe you don't want one.

As some commenters have also noted, your loop will still execute up to 50 iterations, even if `len` is larger than 50. Using a traditional `if..else` guard as written above will not allow you to do this, so it's *not* equivalent with your code (which also checks the guard condition on each iteration).

Comment: Not quite the same - that check happens once, instead of each iteration

Comment: @Izkata: Yes, that's a very good point!

Comment: `if (i< MAX_VALUE_FOR_I) { loop-by-i; }` looks slippery. Did you by chance mean `if (len< MAX_VALUE_FOR_I)`?

Comment: @gnat Even if so, the correct equivalent wouldn't prevent the loop from running, the OP's code limits the maximum iterations.  To get the same effect: `len = min(len, MAX_VALUE_FOR_I)`

Answer (score 5):

I'd call it a *boundary condition.*

Some boundary conditions have special names, such as timeouts for example, and other boundary conditions are indicative of logical errors, such as an "off-by-one" error.

Comment: Good answer. Might want to clarify that the `i < len` condition is a boundary condition too.

Comment: @SomeGuy "hardcoded boundary condition"?

Comment: I think this is a good answer. Do you feel saying "hardcoded boundary condition" is a meaningful way to distinguish this condition from that which @SomeGuy described?

Comment: @thomas: I'm not totally comfortable with "magic numbers" like the one in your `if`.  Generally, you would define a constant somewhere, like `MAX_VALUE`, and use the constant for the condition instead of the magic number.

Comment: What magic number in what `if`? I'm sorry, I'm confused.

Comment: The `50` is a magic number.  Normally, instead of "hardcoding" a stop value there, you would define a constant at the top of your script, such as `MAX_VALUE`, and say `for (var i = 0; i < len && i < MAX_VALUE; i++)`  But, your mileage may vary; if this is just a small bit of Javascript, it may not matter.  My point is that the "hard coding" aspect of this is not particularly significant.